# Keep running screensaver even pressing any key

Tags: linux-mint, xscreensaver

I'm using Linux Mint 18 on a dell laptop, with screen saver as in

[image]

Since some of themes are very pretty and geometrical, I'd like to keep them running on my laptop on an exposition room, that is, while people walk around and have some coffee break, they could enjoy the beauty of screen saver.

But, in this case, I'd like to lock it on the screen, that is, **even pressing any key or moving the cursor, it should keep running**. Is it possible?

I know how to lock it, but when press any key the password field appears and stay there for some seconds. I don't want this.

Since it is necessary some way to disable it, I suspect to run it on some tty?

Answer (score 0):

Screensavers on Linux are just executables, in the case on my system under `/usr/libexec/xscreensaver`. By default they start the screensaver in a window; pass `-h` to the executable to see what options it supports.

Comment: No useful info on ` -h`. Only the link to webpage.

Comment: Which screensaver executable are you looking at?

Comment: I have `/usr/bin/xscreensaver`

Comment: That's not a screensaver, that's the screensaver manager.

Comment: Hum... I use its gui to choose a lot of possible screensavers, in random order. So, you say that I have to know every one. How to discover?

Comment: Did you try looking in the directory yet?

Comment: Oh, there are many in `/usr/lib/xscreensaver` and a lot of options for `./projectiveplane`, for example, `-root, -window, -mono, -install, -noinstall,  -visual <arg>, -window-id <arg>`